# Change the widget in a QTabWidget

Tags: qt

I can't find the way to replace the `QWidget` of a specific tab in a `QTabWidget`, at runtime. I can use `addTab` then `setCurrentWidget`, but what if I want to set a `QWidget` at tab index 1 only, without adding a new tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is to use a parent `QWidget` as the main `QWidget` in the tab and change out its child whenever you want to change the tab contents.

Technically you're not changing the `QWidget` of the tab itself just the first child of the main `QWidget` in the tab.

For example:

```
QTabWidget* myTabWidget = new QTabWidget();
QWidget* tab1 = new QWidget();
QWidget* tab1Contents = new QWidget( tab1 );

// [1] Setup the first tab.
myTabWidget.addTab( tab1, "1st Tab" );

// [3] If you now want to remove the original contents 
// and replace with something new.
delete tab1Contents;
QWidget* tab1NewContents = new QWidget( tab1 );
```

Of course you can add layouts to `tab1`, `tab1Contents`, and `tab1NewContents` ensure your tab contents look nice!

Answer (score 1):

This utility function does it:

```cpp
void replaceTab(QTabWidget * tabs, int index,
                QWidget * replacement, const QString & label = QString())
{
  Q_ASSERT(tabs && tabs->count() > index)
  tabs->removeTab(index);
  if (replacement) tabs->insertTab(index, replacement, label);
}
```

Comment: If you have more than 1 tab and replace the widget in the current tab with this function then another tab becomes the current tab. This can be fixed with getting the current index with `tabs->currentIndex()` and setting it afterwards with `tabs->setCurrentIndex`.